# Android compare date

Tags: android, date, compare

I am trying to compare two dates in this format.

```
date1 = Wed Jul 13 17:23:33 GMT+02:00 2016
date2 = Wed Jul 13 17:23:31 CEST 2016

if(date1.after(date2){
//my logic
}else if(date1.before(date2){
//my logic
}
```

The comparison seems to have happened only a few times, where it is thought to be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse( 
    "Wed Jul 13 17:23:33 GMT+02:00 2016" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" )
        .withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH ) 
)
.isAfter(
    ZonedDateTime.parse( 
        "Wed Jul 13 17:23:31 CEST 2016" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" )
            .withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH ) 
    )
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

```
String inputX = "Wed Jul 13 17:23:33 GMT+02:00 2016";
String inputY = "Wed Jul 13 17:23:31 CEST 2016";
```

Define a formatting pattern to match your input strings.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );
```

The `ZonedDateTime` class represents a moment, a point on the timeline, with a wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). Specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

```
ZonedDateTime x = ZonedDateTime.parse( inputX , f );
ZonedDateTime y = ZonedDateTime.parse( inputY , f );
```

> x.toString(): 2016-07-13T17:23:33+02:00[GMT+02:00]
>
> y.toString(): 2016-07-13T17:23:31+02:00[Europe/Paris]

In real work, trap for the exception thrown when encountering faulty input.

### Compare

Compare using `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `isEqual`, or  methods. Be aware that the `Comparable::equals` method implementation differs in behavior ([read the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#compareTo-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-)).

```
if( x.isBefore( y ) ) {           // BEFORE
    …
} else if( x.isAfter( y ) ) {     // AFTER
    …
} else if( x.isEqual( y ) ) {     // EQUAL
    …  
} else {                          // UNREACHABLE
    … // Handle error condition. Should be unreachable.
}
```

### Zone

By the way, your two inputs use a very poor choice of formats. The first has only an offset-from-UTC rather than an actual time zone. The second carries a pseudo-zone of "CEST". Such 3-4 letter labels are common in mainstream media, but are not true time zones, are not standardized, and are not even unique(!).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Whenever possible, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging date-time values as text. The *java.time* classes use standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. The `ZonedDateTime` class wisely extends the standard format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets, as seen above in our example.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use `compareTo` method.

```
int compare = date1.compareTo(date2);
```

> compare > 0, if date1 is greater than date2
>
> compare = 0, if date1 is equal to date2
>
> compare < 0, if date1 is smaller than date2

Comment: I had already tried that. I think the problem was `GMT` and `CEST`