# How to get time Interval of date from Day , Hour and Minutes

Tags: java, android

I have variables which store the values

```
int day = Calender.SATURDAY;
int hour = 18;
int minutes = 33;
```

**How can I convert this to Date?** so 
**How I can find the time difference in milliseconds from Current date time?**

*Cases :*

1. If the current date, time pass already passed,
   for example: If the current day is Saturday, and now time is 19: 00, than get the next week date time interval.
2. If the current day is Saturday, and now time is 18: 30,
   (the time interval should be  180000 milliseconds = 3 minutes).

How can I do this in android?
Please help me with finding the proper solution for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android compare date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356184/android-compare-date)

Comment: this is not duplicate , My question is Convert Day of week , hour , minute to date , than find diffreance , differance i can find i need to convert into date @leonardkraemer

Answer (score 0):

Create a Calendar (`Calendar.getInstance()`), set your fields (`cal.set(Calendar.DAY, day)`, etc.) and then call `getTime()` on it - that will return a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

For a proper solution I strongly advise to use the modern functions provided by `java.time` instead of the deprecated `java.util`. Read [this post](https://yawk.at/java.time/) and [Convert java.util.Date to what “java.time” type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639154/convert-java-util-date-to-what-java-time-type) to understand the package. How to get `java.time` on android pre API 26 is described here: [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

If you have read those you can solve your problem along the lines of this example:

```
public void dateStuff() {
    int day = DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.getValue();
    int hour = 18;
    int minutes = 33;
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    int dayDifference = now.getDayOfWeek().getValue() - day;
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDayOfMonth() - dayDifference, hour, minutes);

    long timeDifferenceNano = Duration.between(now, date).getNano();
    long timeDifference = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(timeDifferenceNano);
    if (timeDifference > TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3)) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I did not really understand when the two cases come into play, but I'm sure you can take it from here.